# jQuery: function equal to onkeyup=""

Tags: jquery

Is there a function in jquery equal to onkeyup=""

I already found change() but this only executes the alert when on blur, i want it like live searching when you write "a" (wants to write anton) then it should execute the function.. So when you write 5 words thats like 5 executions..
I tried this too:

```
$('#searchFriends').bind('keyup', function() { 
  alert('you wrote something');
});
```

But this just keeps executes and alerts never ends even if i stop writing something.. :S

Comment: [The alerts stop for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/6ZVFK/) in Chrome. What exactly do you want it to do here? Why are you looking for a keyup event of ""? I don't have an empty string key on my keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$('#search').keyup($.debounce(250, function() {
    alert('You wrote something');
}));
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/LfYve/

You have to include [Ben Alman's Throttle/Debounce](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce/) plugin into your page.

Comment: Try that you self and when you enter something and then stop, it wont stop executing the alerts

Comment: @Karem I don't know what you mean. If I write one word in the input box, I only get one alert which pops up after I stopped writing.

Comment: Ok funny it works right now, why do I have to have this plugin? Isnt there another jquery function for doing this? Sounds weird, doing onkeyup="function()" attribute seem to be easier then but uglier

Comment: @Karem The thing is this: When you write a word, the `keyup` event fires for **every** letter of the word. If your keyup handler executes an Ajax-request, you will have one Ajax-request for each typed letter - this is nonsense. Therefore, what you want to do is execute the handler only after the user typed something and then **stopped** for a moment. So if he writes a word, and then pauses for like 250ms, then is the time to do that Ajax-request. `$.debounce` does that for you - it executes the function only if the user typed something and then stopped for moment (250ms in my example).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about the `alert` showing multiple times, you'll likely find that in many browsers, the input box retains focus even when the alert is showing.

This results in a new `keyup` event firing if you press ENTER to clear the alert box. Clicking the OK button with the mouse will result in no further alerts.

Here's a quick example of using the [jQuery keyup event](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) method: http://jsfiddle.net/CZZbx/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
console.log('you wrote something')
```

if you press enter on that alert you're key uping again and it execute again

It will work better with console.log();

Comment: It's worth noting that console.log method outputs to a console window such as that in Firebug. You'll need to install Firebug if you don't already have it to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [keypress event](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)?

Comment: Can you explain why this is a better choice?